# Disable GoogleAnalytics for testing and development of new versions

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, google-analytics

This question is for the new version of Google Analytics (GA).  So this is for v2, not v1.  I just released v1.01 of my app and everything was going smoothly.  I am trying to implement something for v1.1 that I have no idea how to do right now and I am crawling through it right now and crashing my app left and right during the development.  The next morning when GA updated I saw that the Crashes/Exceptions graph, which was always 0, was up to 25!  But I assume that was just me during development yesterday.

My question is how to disable GA during development/testing so it does not skew my GA graphs.

Answer (score 0):

**For v2 (legacy)**

In your analytics.xml add the follownig line,

```
<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
```

Doing it programatically,

```
// Get singleton using application context.
GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

// Enable debug mode.
myInstance.setDebug(true);
```

Reference for v2 [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#testing)

---

**For v3**

Google has rolled out a newer version for the SDK v3 in which there is **dryRun** flag which needs to be set for testing and debugging.

```
GoogeAnalytics.getInstance(this).setDryRun(true);
```

Reference for v3 [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced#testing)